# qApp in QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, migration

I am a novice to QGIS tasked with updating other developers' plugins from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3.  What is the replacement for `qApp` in QGIS 3 in the following code:

```
    for i, state_db in enumerate(db_list):
        if len(db_list) > 1:
            progress.text_val.setText('Opening '+ state_db)  # DialogProcessBar update
            qApp.processEvents()
        self.openStateDb(state_db)
        if len(db_list) > 1:
            progress.progressBar.setValue(i * step)
            qApp.processEvents()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the qApp object is replaced by QDialog. Therefore:

`qApp.processEvents()`

becomes

`QDialog.processEvents()`